# Scheduling for the day before (or after) the nth weekday of the month

Tags: microsoft-outlook, scheduled-tasks

I've been thinking about this a lot lately because its come up twice for me recently.  Using *Outlook*, how can I schedule something for `the day before the nth Wednesday of the month`?  Since a month can start on any day of the week the 2nd Tuesday could precede the 3rd Wednesday (these are all examples).  And vice versa, how about `the day after the second Tuesday of the month`, how do I schedule that.
The best I can come up with for "the day before" is to use a reminder that is sufficiently far in advance.  I can't find an idea for the day after at all.

Comment: Consider manually creating the meetings rather than recurring, if it's a single meeting once per month

Comment: While that may be the only solution, it fails to act as the memory that I need to do the task.  I'm really surprised this hasn't been solved.  While rare, I have now accumulated two use cases for this.

Comment: What about if the nth Wednesday of the month or the day after/before, one or both falls on a public holiday?

Comment: In excel it's possible to create a formula to calculate your days [as explained in this tutorial](https://www.contextures.com/exceldatenthdaymonth.html) - just add/subtract a day from the given formula. So you can create your appointments in excel and then link / import such excel into outlook [as explained here](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/create-calendar-excel-data). Writing a self-contained answer based on this would exceed my available time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are two methods, one purely manual and the other uses Excel in
addition to Outlook. Both methods may be more work than just manually
creating the meetings, but they do answer the question.

**Method 1 : Manual**

- In Outlook, create the series for the nth Wednesday of the month
- Per each individual meeting, modify it to be one day before
  (or after).

It's possible to modify this way each individual meeting in the series,
without affecting the rest of the series.

**Method 2 : Export/Import via Excel**

- In Outlook, create a new temporary calendar, say named Temp
- In Temp, create the series for the nth Wednesday of the month
- Export Temp to a CSV file
- Use Excel to open the CSV file
- Add (or subtract) 1 day from all the dates (in one operation)
- Import the CSV file back into Outlook main calendar.

For more detailed information on the above, see:

- [3 Ways to Add or Subtract Days to a Date](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/add-subtract-days-to-date/) (Excel)
- [Changing the End Date on Recurring Appointments](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/changing-date-recurring-appointments/)
  The article itself is not interesting, except that it details how to
  export a recurring meeting to a CSV file.

Comment: I'm starting to think the  export/import is the best method available.

Comment: Good sharing! I have also tried harrymc's Method 2, this can completely achieve the effect of displaying the day before or after the nth working day on the calendar by changing the .csv file!

Comment: My procedure was overly complicated, so I simplified it by having the recurring meeting directly created in Temp.

Comment: Thank you for your update! If harrymc's suggestion is confirmed to help you, it is recommended that you could mark it as the answer so that users with similar questions can get reference.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Steven, since you only need to set up a calendar item once a month for a specific day, it won't be troublesome to create it manually.

According to my tests on the outlook client, there seems to be no way to set this directly. As a workaround, it's suggested that you could try to change your time zone to a time zone 24 hours earlier than the current time zone(File>Options>Calendar>Time zones) and create a nth weekday of the month calendar item. Then switch back to your original time zone. In this way, the meeting will be displayed the day before a nth weekday of the month in the original time zone, which can meet your expectations.

Comment: +1 for the creative potential work-around.

Comment: If my suggestion is helpful to you, would you mind marking it as the answer so that users with similar questions can get reference?

Comment: While I appreciate the answer, I don't believe it answers the question directly.  I'm going to leave it open for now. I'm considering a bounty

Comment: Well, hope your problem will be solved as soon as possible~

Comment: One more thing, Given I'm at UTC - 5:00, I suspect I cannot set my timezone back more than 17 hours.  Timezones only range 24 hours total and I'm 3/4ths the way through.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Can you tell me the specific time of the meeting you want to set? Maybe we can combine the time zone and meeting time to grope the helpful method.

Comment: Time zone only goes up to 23:59 hours, so the meeting can never be on the right time when in another time zone. Secondly, the nth Wednesday on another time zone that falls on another day, is not guaranteed to be the nth Wednesday on your time zone. Thirdly, any meeting messages sent when the meeting is created will have a wrong date.

Comment: In addition, have you tried it? If the meeting time is specified in UTC, then changing the time zone will automatically move the meeting back/forward in time.

Comment: Of course I've tried! I tested the time zone of (UTC-10:00) Hawaii. After I switched the time zone to (UTC+14:00 Kiritimati Island) and created a recurring meeting on the third Wednesday of each month, I switched back to (UTC-10:00) Hawaii again. The recurring meeting on the day before the third Wednesday of each month can be displayed on the current calendar.

Answer (score 2):

I am providing two alternatives, which are likely most simple in terms of required steps/operation speed.

The balance of (time invested in getting acquainted with and using each solution) vs. (time saved in the operation / reduction of propensity to errors) depends very much on how often you will need to use it.
This applies to any solution here or in other answers.
If you mean to set up quite a few of these meetings and/or have a recurrence that spans several weeks, then I would go with method 2.

### Method 1

This is a much simpler variant on "the time zones method".

1. Create a meeting.
2. Tick on *Time zones*
3. If you want a meeting for "the day before the nth Wednesday at `HH:MM`" (say, at 2pm, `HH:MM = 14:00`), setup your recurring meeting for the nth Wednesday, at UTC+12, at `hh:MM`, with `hh = (HH+5+12) mod 24`, in the example `hh=7`. Number 5 stems from your UTC-5, number 12 stems form the UTC+12 used for the meeting. Given that HH:MM range from 00:00 to 23:59, that allows you starting your meetings no earlier than 7am, but that doesn't look  like a problem. **I have just tested this (I am at UTC-3), and it works nicely**. Note that there exists UTC+14, remarkably...
4. If you want a meeting for "the day after the nth Tuesday at `HH:MM`", you could use a similar method, with UTC-12. Given that you are at UTC-5, this only gives you the chance of starting meetings no later than 6:59am, probably useless.

### Method 2

Use VBA.
Perhaps the easiest way would be to setup the recurring meeting as usual, and use a VBA macro to change the time to one day earlier or later.
You could record a macro while you perform these operations, and this gives you the basic structure of your macro. The resulting dates in the recorded macro would be fixed. You could edit the macro to apply the simple required math to compute the date instead of the fixed values.

This would take some time to put together (depending on your programming/VBA skills, it might be anything from 30 minutes to infinite), but perhaps not more than an alternative via Excel ([1](https://superuser.com/questions/1668879/scheduling-for-the-day-before-or-after-the-nth-weekday-of-the-month/1670836#comment2561380_1668879), [2](https://superuser.com/a/1670313/245595)).

The advantage of this is that once you have it, it is much simpler/faster than the others. Plus, you can add a button to your ribbon to make it even easier.

Note: I have my personal `VbaProject.OTM` that I carry and update over the years with some 100 macros that save me a lot of time, and reduce significantly the chance of errors.

[image] (although there are a few things not accessible to VBA in the MSOffice landscape).

Answer (score 1):

**You can manually do that!** :

- Change your timezone to a timezone which is a day earlier or a day late than your current time zone
- You can do it by **clicking file options calendar.** And create a nth weekday of the month calendar

Then switch back to your original time zone. In this way, the meeting will be showed a day before a nth weekday of the month in the original time zone!

Comment: Time zone only goes up to 23:59 hours, so the meeting can never be on the right time when in another time zone. Secondly, the nth Wednesday on another time zone that falls on another day, is not guaranteed to be the nth Wednesday on your time zone. Thirdly, any meeting messages sent when the meeting is created will have a wrong date.

Comment: .. this is basically the same answer as the one from @Christy, only written in a different way. See the comments to that answer !

Answer (score 0):

All this is fine and good (I guess); but why can't Microsoft solve this problem?? It has been this way forever, and nothing ever changes.
Many years ago, we used Novell Groupwise, and they had the ability to do everything you could think of in days before/after, etc.
Get with it, Microsoft, and give us what we have been asking for!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1151815)