# Outlook - Recurring Meeting X days before 1st Monday of Each Month?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I see that there's a way to create a recurring meeting on the first/second/third/fourth weekday of each month, but I was wondering if there was a way to add in relative time to this.

For example, if I want to schedule a presentation on the first Monday of each month, and a prep day on the prior Friday. That could be either the last Friday of the previous month, or the first Friday of the current month.

Comment: Hi and welcome to superuser! Please take a moment to read about [asking a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) as this increases the chances of getting an answer. I am especially curious about the first point: what did your research show so far? Have you done any websearches? What did you find? Why did the found solutions not work? Please [edit] this into your question, this makes it easier for other to help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scheduling for the day before (or after) the nth weekday of the month](https://superuser.com/questions/1668879/scheduling-for-the-day-before-or-after-the-nth-weekday-of-the-month)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the blog is more suitable for your situation: [Schedule a recurring meeting X days before or after another recurring meeting](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/793)

There provided 3 methods, you could choose one which is most suitable for you.

- Reminder
- Approximate and move the exceptions
- Export, Calculate and Import via Excel

Comment: Do above suggestions help you? You could mark the helpful reply as best answer or share your solution, your action will be helpful to others who encounters the same issue.